# Как с помощью Scanner считывать строку полностью, с учётом пробелов?

Tags: java, input, scanner

У меня есть такой код:

```
System.out.print("Input a Dream: ");
String dream_input = input.next();
System.out.print("Input a Status: ");
String s_status_input = input.next();
```

Он считывает только слово, до первого пробела. Его естественная функция. Но мне надо записать строку слов целиком. Везде предлагается метод использования `nextLine()`, но есть одно НО:
При его использовании, при отображении в консоле вместо первой фразы "

```
"Input a Dream:"
```

" отображается сразу всё:

```
"Input a Dream: Input a Status: "
```

после чего можно заполнить только одну переменную - `s_status_input`.
Как мне написать так, чтобы я смог ввести две фразы **раздельно** и каждая записалась в нужную переменную?

Comment: Только-только начал учить Java, нужна ваша поддержка и помощь. Заранее благодарю!

Comment: nextLine метод, вместо next

Comment: я и описал проблему, что при использовании nextLine() у меня вторая строчка съезжает и выходит так: ```"Input a Dream: Input a Status: "```

Comment: @Bogdan в том примере что вы скинули просто меняете next() на nextLine() как вам уже и сказали. если больше ничего не напутали нигде, то это точно будет работать как надо. Если так и не работает скидывайте код целиком, надо искать ошибку в другом месте.

Comment: @Bogdan, я запустил Ваш пример, заменив input.next() на input.nextLine() и программа работает именно так, как Вы хотите. Можете дать больше сведений о Вашей версии Java, операционной системе и, возможно, выложить весь оставшийся код?

Comment: я использую сайт ```onlinegdb``` потому, что у меня нет своего компа и не могу установить IDE. Браузер яндекс. Я и правда до того как сюда написал, попробовал заменить next() на nextLine(). В коде нет ничего, что влияет на конкретно этот вывод. Там описан обычный свитч кейс, и в нем мы вводим переменные, если нажата 1. switch (choice){ case "1": ... (дальше код с вводом)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это странно, ваш код рабочий и работает так, как вы и задумывали, причём без `nextLine()`
Попробуйте скомпилировать этот класс:

```
  import java.io.InputStreamReader;
  import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.print("Input a Dream: ");
        String dream_input = scanner.next();
        System.out.print("Input a Status: ");
        String s_status_input = scanner.next();
        System.out.println(dream_input);
        System.out.println(s_status_input);
    }
}
```

Консоль:

```
Input a Dream: dream
Input a Status: status
dream
stastus
```

На онлайн компиляторе `onlinegdb`, о котором вы говорили код тоже правильно работает

Comment: спасибо большое. вот это сработало!

Comment: @Bogdan если ответ решил вашу проблему, пожалуйста, указывайте его как решение, нажав на символ галочки рядом с ответом.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте ввести

```
"Input a Dream:\nInput a Status: "
```

Это должно сработать, в случае

```java
System.out.print("Input a Dream: ");
String dream_input = input.nextLine();
System.out.print("Input a Status: ");
String s_status_input = input.nextLine();
```

Answer (score 1):

)))

```
   System.out.print("Input a Dream: \n");
    String dream_input = input.next();
    System.out.print("Input a Status: ");
    String s_status_input = input.next();
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]